In the following example, is it possible for the function to be inlined?
C11  6.7.4 p6:

A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline
function.

and:
6.7.4 p7:

Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. For a
function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a
function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it shall
also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the file scope
declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline
function specifier without extern, then the definition in that
translation unit is an inline definition.

Then, if a function is an inline function but there is no inline definition of it in the current translation unit. For example, extern inline int foo(){...} , For foo(); , is it still possible for it to be inlined rather than being a call?(extern inline int foo(){...}  does not meet the requirements for an inline definition. It creates an external definition. foo is an inline function, but the definition of the function is not an inline definition.)
In other words, does the chance of a function being inlined depend on whether the function is an inline function or on whether the function has an inline definition?

A C implementation may inline any function, provided it does not change the semantics (e.g., create a second instance of a static object). The implementation’s only obligation is to maintain observable behavior as specified by the C standard, and whether a function is inlined or not does not affect observable behavior.

Why is it important for you to know the chance? Since the standard does not specify an obligation, a compiler is free to ignore the specifier. It may or may not inline a function. By my experience this depends heavily on the optimization.

If the question is "Can the word inline affect if a function is inlined?", then the answer is "Yes, but not by much". You can read the source of open source compilers and see what they do, and people have done that. It turns out that an inline in the function declaration adds extra points for inlining. However, most short functions that will be inlined, don't need any extra points. It is only for border-case decisions that these points may (or may not) tip the scale over.

You said: Then, if a function is an inline function but there is no inline definition of it in the current translation uni … is it still possible for it to be inlined rather than being a call? I believe the answer is "No".  You must have a definition of the function visible in the current translation unit (TU) for the function to be inlined.  It's conceivable the with "link time optimization" a compiler might inline functions, but I think it is an error if there is an inline declaration with no inline definition in a TU.
